# How to correctly authenticate users with same email and password?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

In my users table i have additional column that stores the information to which specific scope user belongs and for our application needs a different scope can have same email and password.

My problem is that when i call /oauth/token URL i can get a token for a wrong user if there are 2 rows with same email and password.

Is there an way to call that method and passing additional custom field?

For example, if i have:

```
$response = $http->request('POST', env('APP_URL') . '/api/oauth/token', [
  'form_params' => [
  'grant_type' => 'password',
  'client_id' => $oClient->id,
  'client_secret' => $oClient->secret,
  'username' => $request->email,
  'password' => $request->password,
  'scope' => 'business',
],
]);
```

is there any way to add additional parameter in there like

```
$response = $http->request('POST', env('APP_URL') . '/api/oauth/token', [
      'form_params' => [
      'grant_type' => 'password',
      'client_id' => $oClient->id,
      'client_secret' => $oClient->secret,
      'username' => $request->email,
      'password' => $request->password,
      'user_role' => 'example_role'
      'scope' => 'business',
    ],
    ]);
```

Comment: *"2 rows with same email and password"* - That should never happen. Email and Password combinations _should_ be unique; in real life, 2 people cannot have the same Email, so why would you allow this in your database?

Comment: Sounds like a "not so optimal" database design. Make `scope` a table of its own (referencing your users/login/auth table), not a column

Comment: Wouldn't it be an option to merge these rows and have scoped stored in a column?